# In situ preparation of Potassium Tert-Butoxide

Tags: solvents

I am attempting to prepare potassium *tert*-butoxide. I was going to suspend anhydrous toluene and anhydrous *tert*-butanol, dissolve (reflux) the potassium metal (pure), then distill the excess *tert*-butanol as a benzene azeotrope.

2 questions.

1. The metal comes stored in mineral oil. Should I rinse it in toluene to get the oil off?
2. How will the presence of oxides effect the reaction (if at all). If so, how can I mitigate this?

Comment: tBuOK is supposed to be well soluble in THF, and badly in toluene.Where does the benzene come from? Don't use benzene if at all avoidable, everything else is very bad practice. You should filter the K-butoxide solution to remove any residual oxide etc. That way also the solvents dry themselves during the reaction without any further step.